# QGIS "Loading Python support" takes too long

Tags: qgis, python, windows

Starting a local QGIS installation (3.34.4, installed with OSGeo4W) on Windows 10 takes a very long time (>1min). A look at the debugging/development tools shows that the entry "Loading python support" takes 46s. It is not quite clear to me what exactly is being done here by QGIS and why loading Python + a few third party libraries takes so long.

Are there any adjustments that can be made to shorten the loading time or known factors that have a negative influence on the loading time?

Comment: Windows? Maybe a overzealous "antivirus"?

Comment: Windows shouldn't be an issue in general. The antivirus was switched off for testing purpose with no effect.

Comment: And does it take the same amount of time when starting QGIS with a fresh profile? Settings -> User Profiles -> New Profile...

Comment: yes, it has absolutely no effect

Comment: I'd start checking which files are accessed using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the status "Loading Python support" also includes the execution of the ***pre-startup script*** referenced in `PYQGIS_STARTUP`. In this we did e.g. a comparison of the contents of two network drives (user profile + additional network drive) using filecmp.dircmp(), which took too long due to our network performance. After removing this part of code, the start time improved massively.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-pyqgis-startup-environment-variable

Comment: Do you mean `startup.py` or `PYQGIS_STARTUP`?

Answer (score 4):

One reason could be if your %USERPROFILE% is not on your local disk for example a network drive. In some cases QGIS uses this path for the `Start in` / `Ausführen in`. In my case, changing `Start in` to a folder on `C:\` solved the very slow start up of QGIS.

Properties of the QGIS-Exe or the shorcut of the QGIS-exe:

[image: Properties of QGIS Executable]

Comment: QGIS initializes Python and searches through various paths for modules and plugins. If the Python path (PYTHONPATH) is excessively long or includes directories with many files, it could slow down the startup. Try to keep the Python environment clean and minimal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I have found the cause. Apparently it was due to our pre-startup script, which compared the contents of two network drives with filecmp.dircmp() and took an excessively long time to do so (for whatever reason)

Comment: I highly recommend posting this as an answer because it raises every user's awareness of what they are writing in their startup script!